# Fine Uploader - upload all files in one folder

Tags: fine-uploader

I have setup Fine Uploader to upload to own server.
By default it creates a new folder for each uploaded file, for example

```
/uploadfolder/guid1/file1.txt
/uploadfolder/guid2/file2.txt
```

How do I change that to upload to one folder?

```
/uploadfolder/guid1/file1.txt<br>
/uploadfolder/guid1/file2.txt<br>
```

For endpoint I use the [PHP traditional server code from github](https://github.com/FineUploader/php-traditional-server).

Comment: Fine Uploader doesn't create any folders on your server. Your server creates folders on your server.

Comment: That doesnt realy help, Ray.

Comment: ...and neither did your original question, which provided absolutely no information about your server code. As it stands, this is still a poorly written question and may very well be closed since there is no hint of an attempt to solve the problem and nothing more than links to existing code. Why on earth would you want to place all files in the same folder. Are you not concerned about collisions? The simple answer is: update the targetDirectory at https://github.com/FineUploader/php-traditional-server/blob/master/handler.php#L54.

Comment: "Why on earth would you want to place all files in the same folder." For ease of file listing. Having 1000 folders named "d64783-74gdt-4hf6d7" makes it harder to find something inside.

"Are you not concerned about collisions?" 
In this particular case - No.

"The simple answer is: update the targetDirectory" 
Thank you, this does help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server side, in handler.php, you can change

return array("success" => true, "uuid" => $uuid);

into

return array("success" => true, "uuid" => NULL);

Answer (score 0):

Adding the "uuidName" parameter seems to work - the uploaded files get dropped into one folder.

```
<script>
var multiFileUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
                    element: document.getElementById("myFileDropArea"),
                    request: {
                        endpoint: 'FineUploader/endpoint.php',
                        uuidName: 'myFolder'
                    }
                });
</script>
```